# How to clear backstack in android?

Tags: android

I have a Splash screen and have Main Activity ,Scenario is that in Main Activity there is a condition which check Login is true or not and have  a "Login" activity and have a Fragment called "B".when I pressed device back button in "Login" activity it Main Activity comes.which I don't want I simple want to close app when I press device back button in Login activity.

here is my code for Back Pressed in Login activity:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please  again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: When you know user is not logged in and opening LoginActivity, just call `finish()`

Comment: pass `finish()` when you are passing `Intent`..this will finish current activity and start new one and when back is pressed in new one app will close ans app will exit..

Comment: when I press back MainActivity comes

Comment: can you post code on intent you are passing to MainActivity ...

Comment: see MainActivity is different which add some fragment and Login Activity is different and there is splash screen which check some condition if condition true it will show MainActivity with added fragment and if false then it will show Login Activity............when I press back in Login activity MainActivity comes with added fragment .......I don't want MainActivity to come simple close app

Comment: post code of your login screen ..

Comment: won't add your fragment in backstack

Comment: add finish() where  you calling that Activity intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `finish()` method in the Intent creator activity.

If you have 2 activities - A and B, and A starts B via Intent, without going back to A, the Intent in A will look like this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
```

Comment: where I have to write this code in Login or MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

write the following lines

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish(); 
}
```

Here, on back pressed the above method will be called and it will finish the activity.

Comment: Kindly please see understand the question, he want to clear the back stack not close the screen.